# how angular $inject is working in background

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i know how to use $inject in my project.

```
angular.module("myApp",["ngRouter"]);
angualr.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl",myCtrl);
myCtrl.$inject=["$scope"];
function myCtrl(sc){
sc.a=10;
sc.b=20;
}
```

my question is how myCtrl is able to have $inject as property and take array of injectables.As per my understanding one can do

```
Function.prototype.$inject=[]; //assigning $inject to Function prototypes
//then we can use
function a(){
this.a=10;this.b=20}
a.$inject=[1,2,3]
```

if i am right till here then please explain what might be next steps?
If i am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to expose the $injector outside of angular (but **after** the angular's bootstrap has been executed) you can do the following:

```
angular.module("myApp").run(['$injector', function($injector){
    angular.$$injector = $injector;
}]);
```

**Keep in mind that this is an hack, and if you want to use angular you shoud write your code in the angular's way.**

Example usage:

```
function myButtonPressed(){
    // make an $http call
    var $http = angular.$$injector.get('$http');
    $http.get(/*......*/);
}
```

**Update**:
If you want to know how angular works I can try to explain the concept by keeping it simple.

Angular has some kind of "singleton repository" (that in some cases depends on the context of execution - like `$scope`) where all objects has to be registered in varius ways.

Now, when you define a controller (that is a function) in Angular using the `module.controller( function or array here )` it stores your function and it assigns a `$inject` property (like you do in your example) with and array of "singleton's identifiers".

Angular knows when to execute your controller's function and knows how to call it so:

1. Angular looks in the `$inject` property and using `$injector` service obtains all the instances in the exact order and puts them into an array `argsArray`
2. Angular uses `YourControllerFunction.apply(null, argsArray)` to execute the controller's code

Il this the information you were looking for?

Comment: hi @Alberto i am asking how things are working in background(angular code) but not how  can i get injector outside angular.Anyways i learned a new thing here

Comment: Hi, @bharathmuppa I updated the answer hoping to solve your doubts